# GOGCTRACE and collection time

Tags: logging, garbage-collection, go

Go supports a [GOGCTRACE](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) environment variable, and prints collection statistics on each run. However it doesn't print when the GC occurred. Example:

> gc6231(8): 0+1+0 ms, 10 -> 5 MB 89540 -> 5294 (520316701-520311407) objects, 9(80) handoff, 32(404) steal, 288/168/37 yields

How do I correlate a collection line, with the time it occurred?

Comment: Looks like GOGCTRACE is no more supported: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-dev/137p2tm5f1/has-gogctrace-been-removed-or-renamed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trace does not show an absolute time but one relative to the output.
When the line occurs the GC happened `0 + 1 + 0` ms ago.

See [the corresponding output line](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/mgc0.c?name=release-branch.go1.1#2056) in the code for reference.

If you prefix each line on stdout with a timestamp you then get the time of the GC run
(timestamp - time in milliseconds = time the GC ran).

Example:

```
GOGCTRACE=1 ./myprog 2>&1 | while read line; do echo $(date +%s) $line; done
```

If you just want to have a feeling when a GC run happened with accuracy of seconds
then this is totally sufficient. The output will most likely not lag behind much and
even if it does, you'd still have the timestamps to get the correct time.

Another solution would be to use [`ReadGCStats`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#ReadGCStats) from `runtime/debug` which gives you
the [`GCStats`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#GCStats) struct, which in turn has a 
field `LastGC` of type `time.Time`, holding the absolute time of the last GC run.
Alternatively you can use [`runtime.ReadMemStats`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats), which gives you even more information.

Of course you would still need to know when a garbage collection happened. For this you could
use a finalizer on a object which you create solely for the purpose of being garbage 
collected and apply [`runtime.SetFinalizer`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer) on it. 
In the finalizer you would then read the `LastGC` time and print it.

Example (on [play](http://play.golang.org/p/nb8SawIxg0)):

```
type Garbage struct{ a int }

func notify(f *Garbage) {
    stats := &runtime.MemStats{}
    runtime.ReadMemStats(stats)

    fmt.Println("Last GC was:", stats.LastGC)

    go ProduceFinalizedGarbage()
}

func ProduceFinalizedGarbage() {
    x := &Garbage{}
    runtime.SetFinalizer(x, notify)
}

func main() {
    go ProduceFinalizedGarbage()

    for {
        runtime.GC()
        time.Sleep(30 * time.Second) // Give GC time to run
    }
}
```

Comment: I require an absolute time the GC occurred.

Comment: So? If you have the relative time and you prefix every line with the absolute time then you can see the absolute time of the GC run. For example: `./myprog | while read line; do echo $(date +%s) $line; done`.

Comment: This answer is thoroughly informing, bravo.

Comment: Glad you like it, did it help though?